# Bounding the Number of Non-isomorphic Graphs having $m$ Edges and no isolated vertex

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I had this question in my mind for quite sometime:

Given a positive integer $m$, what is the sharpest known bound on the number of non-isomorphic (connected or disconnected) graphs having exactly $m$ edges and no isolated vertex?

I would be happy if there is an upper bound of the form $poly(m)$ or even something like $m^{\log m}$, but I have no idea how to prove or disprove these. Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: The numbers are given by [this sequence](http://oeis.org/A000664).

Comment: It's going to be at least the number of $m$-edge trees, which is exponential in $m$. (A crude lower bound from Cayley's theorem is $\frac{(m+1)^{m-1}}{(m+1)!}$.)

Comment: Thanks! Is there any upper bound of the form $m^{m^\alpha}$ for some $\alpha < 1$?